# How to check a specific string in List on a SQL Select statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, soql

I was wondering if its possible to add a condition like the code below in a select statement, and if it is, how should I do it ?

code that looks like these

> SELECT first_name ,last_name FROM persons_table [condition: WHERE last_name is on exclusiveList]

Comment: How would one know if the person is on the exclusiveList to begin with? Is it stored in a separate table? In memory? A field in the user itself?

Comment: it could be on a separate table, but I am thinking to put them on a map or list which I could access in the select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your exclusiveList is on another table you can do:

```
SELECT first_name ,last_name FROM persons_table 
WHERE last_name in (select lastName from exclusiveListTable)
```

or even nicer: use join as a filter:

```
select * from  -- or select A.* from
(SELECT first_name ,last_name FROM persons_table) A
inner join
(select lastName from exclusiveListTable ) B
on A.last_name = B.lastName
```

Comment: thanks, I was almost thinking the same code in your first example . Glad you wrote the right code! Also, thanks for the new idea on the second example
have to read about the use of join before trying that one :)

Comment: yes you were almost there:)  if it helped you - please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
SELECT first_name ,last_name FROM persons_table 
WHERE last_name in ('name1','name2',,,,'nameN')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_name ,last_name FROM persons_table 
WHERE last_name in (select name from table2)
```

OR

```
SELECT first_name ,last_name FROM persons_table 
WHERE Exists(select top 1 name from table2 where table2.columnname=persons_table.last_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME,'REGEXP');
```